# Trying to run face_recognition package

Tags: ros, tutorial, face-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, total noob here trying to follow the tutorial for the [face_recognition](http://wiki.ros.org/face_recognition) package.

Anyways, so I cloned the face_recognition from the github site, but now how do I add it to my ros packages so that commands such as roscd, rosrun will recognize it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91671/trying-to-run-face_recognition-package/) by [robotnewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/7851/robotnewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you place the newly downloaded package under ROS_PACKAGE_PATH then you just run the command "rospack profile", "roscd" should be able to find it.

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2013-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1